# Multiplying singles and decimals

Tags: vba

```
 If btnTotalCost.Text = "Calculate total cost" Then

        btnTotalCost.Text = "Refresh"
    Else

        btnTotalCost.Text = "Calculate total cost"
    End If

    Dim dHamSandwich As Decimal = 1.35

    Dim sHamQuantity As Single

    txtHam.Text = sHamQuantity

    dTotalSandwichCost = dHamSandwich * sHamQuantity

    If btnTotalCost.Text = "Refresh" Then
        MsgBox(dTotalSandwichCost)


    End If
```

When I calculate the message box that appears shows the number 0. I want it to multiply the quantity and the cost to give the total cost of the sandwich. For example, if I input 2 into the quantity text box, it should multiply 1.35 by 2.

Comment: What's the data type of dTotalSandwichCost? Also, you have tagged this question as VBA but I don't think VBA has a Decimal data type, and it doesn't allow you to Dim and set value all on one line. Could this be VB.Net?

Comment: I think it is, my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you should specify EXACTLY what you use. As the comment of Ste Griffiths suggest, it seems to be VB.NET.

Secondly please start learning the usage of data types and variables.

You do

```
Dim dHamSandwich As Decimal = 1.35 ' <- this is fine

Dim sHamQuantity As Single '<- this is an uninitialised Single variable, in .net it will be set to 0

txtHam.Text = sHamQuantity '<- then you assign the unassigned Single variable to your Textbox's property Text(which requires a string)  
'That means it will implicitly convert the Single to String and then "show" it in the textbox (which will be 0)

dTotalSandwichCost = dHamSandwich * sHamQuantity 'here you multiply 1.35 * 0. Sure it will be 0. Also you multiply a decimal with a single data type which will implicitly convert the latter (if I remember correctly)
```

The question for me here is. Why do you even use Single and Decimal? You can use either one. But the main problem is actually not even the data types, but the assignment.

Comment: I use the singles to input the quantity of the amount of sandwiches. The text box contains the word "quantity" in it. Then I want to change this into a variable so it will change to 0. Then I can input the quantity of sandwiches that the user desires.

Comment: You cannot change a textbox to a "Variable". The easiest approach would be to use Decimal.TryParse -https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx with the TextHam.Text and use that for calculation. What you try to do would be smth like Databinding. If you assign txtHam.Text = sHamQuantity it will only copy the value of sHamQuantity to the Text Property of the Textbox. But it wont magically update the sHamQuantity variable when you change something in the textbox.

Comment: How would I use Decimal.TryParse argument with my txtHam.Text?